# hitTestObject issue // remove stage Error #2025

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

hey :S I`m trying to make 2 things so far but neither work :(

The 1st is to make an Row of 5 Ships that position them selves from the top to left.Then add an Event to make them move down.
But every time i try to make a new Row of 5 new ships ... they position themselves after the last ship from the previous Row.I did think of a way to fix that by waiting the 1st Row of ships to go beyond the stage and then remove them from the stage and splice from the Array but ... when I increase the speed of spawning (when i have 2 rows with 5 ships on the stage or more)that does't work.

And the second error I think is from that fact .... that I have 2 rows at the same time on the stage.

```
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
at MainClass/doShips()
at MainClass/everyFrame()
```

I dont know what exactly to paste from the code so i had to push everything in the MainClass of the FLA.fail :D but i did it neatly! so if anyone helped me he would track the code easily

so its a simple FLA.fail with 4 MC and in those 4 MC there is no code 
a Bullet
a Ship with colour Yellow
a Ship2 with colour Green  so i can see the randomising 
and a Player with the class Turret

so the MainClass of the FLA is :

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class MainClass extends MovieClip {

    protected var mouseSpeed:Number = 20;
    protected var _thePlayer:Turret = new Turret();
    protected var shipCount:Number;
    protected var shipCount2:Number;
    protected var shipArray:Array = new Array();
    protected var counter:int = 0;

    //variables for bullets
    private var shootCooldown:Number = 0; //speed of the fire 
    private var firing:Boolean = false;//bullets triger
    private var numToShoot:int = 1; //bullets
    const MAX_COOLDOWN = 10; //bullets timer
    protected var _bulletsArray:Array = new Array();


    public function MainClass() {
        _thePlayer.x = stage.stageWidth/2
        _thePlayer.y = stage.stageHeight - _thePlayer.height/2
        addChild(_thePlayer)
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, everyFrame)
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startFire);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopFire);
    }
    private function startFire(ev:MouseEvent) {
        firing = true;
    }
    private function stopFire(ev:MouseEvent) {
        firing = false;
    }

    //every frame do this
    protected function everyFrame(ev:Event):void{
        //Moving The Turret
        moveTheTurret();
        //increase the counter every frame
        counter++;
        if(counter % 70 == 0){
            //position the ships on the stage
            positionShips();
        }
        //handle the ships when they are added on the stage
        doShips();
        //when to fire
        updateFire();
        //handle the bullets
        doBullets();
    }

    //Moving The Turret
    protected function moveTheTurret() {
        if (mouseX > _thePlayer.x +15) {
            _thePlayer.x +=  mouseSpeed;
        } else if (mouseX < _thePlayer.x - 15) {
            _thePlayer.x -=  mouseSpeed;
        } else {
            _thePlayer.x = mouseX;
        }
    }


    //createShips and position them
    protected function positionShips() {
        shipCount = 3;
        shipCount2 = 2;
        var gap = 10;
        for (var i:int = 0; i < shipCount; i++) {
            var s = new Ship();
            shipArray.push(s);
        }
        for (var j:int = 0; j < shipCount2; j++) {
            s = new Ship2();
            shipArray.push(s);
        }
        var array:Array=new Array();
        while (shipArray.length>0) {
            var index:uint = Math.floor(Math.random() * shipArray.length);
            array.push(shipArray[index]);
            shipArray.splice(index,1);
        }
        shipArray = array;
        //shipsArray has been randomized
        for (var k:int = shipArray.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            addChild(shipArray[k]);
            shipArray[k].x = shipArray[k].width/2 + (shipArray[k].width * k) + (gap*k);
        }
    }


    //move the ships
    protected function doShips() {
        for (var i:int = shipArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            shipArray[i].y +=3 //make the Ships fall down

            for (var bcount= _bulletsArray.length-1; bcount >= 0; bcount--) {
                //if the bullet is touching the ship
                if (shipArray[i].hitTestObject(_bulletsArray[bcount])) {
                    //if we get here it means there`s is a collision
                    removeChild(_bulletsArray[bcount]);
                    _bulletsArray.splice(bcount,1);
                    removeChild(shipArray[i]);
                    _bulletsArray.splice(i,1);
                }
            }
            //if it gets over 380 remove from stage and splice from the array
            if(shipArray[i].y  > 380){ // stage.stageHeight)
                removeChild(shipArray[i]);
                shipArray.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
    }


    //when to fire
    public function updateFire() {
        //if we are currently holding the mouse down
        if(firing == true){
            fire();
        }
        //reduce the cooldown by 1 every frame
        shootCooldown--;
    }


    //Shoot bullets
    private function fire() {
        if (shootCooldown <= 0) {
            //reset the cooldown 
            shootCooldown = MAX_COOLDOWN
            for (var i=0; i<numToShoot; i++){
                //spown a bullet
                var b = new Bullet();
                //set the rotation of the bullet
                b.rotation = -90
                b.x = _thePlayer.x;
                b.y = _thePlayer.y;
                //add the bullet to the list/Array of _bulletsArray
                _bulletsArray.push(b);
                //add the bullet to the perent object;
                addChild(b);
            }
        }
    }


    //handling the bullets
    protected function doBullets(){
        //make a for loop to iterate all  the _bulletsArray on the screen
        for (var bcount:int = _bulletsArray.length-1; bcount>=0; bcount--) {
            //make the bullets move Up
            _bulletsArray[bcount].y -=20;
            //if the bullet is beyond the screen remove from the stage and the Array
            if(_bulletsArray[bcount].y < 0){
                removeChild(_bulletsArray[bcount])
                _bulletsArray.splice(bcount,1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

I dont know how to fix neither of the 2 problems.Would be very thankful for any help!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Haven't really looked at your code in detail, but the error you're getting means that you're trying to remove a DisplayObject (which can be a Sprite or MovieClip) from the display stack (or i your case, off the stage directly) , but it is no longer on the display stack/stage. It would look at each of your removeChild() calls in doShips() starting by tracing them out to see if any are null or have already been removed from the stage.

Comment: yea ... i was splicing the wrong array ....yet now a new error comes


`TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at MainClass/doShips()
 at MainClass/everyFrame()`


any ideas ?

Comment: That error literally means something you're trying to work with is undefined. Like calling a method or property on a null object, it doesn't exist. Looking a bit closer at your doShips() method, I'd start by tracing out "shipArray[i]" and checking if any of them are null at the start of the loop. You could also try using the debugger which sometimes can point out what line of code is causing this error (control-shift-enter, if using the flash ide).